# Cathcing POST with http-on-modify-request (firefox extension)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to implement POST data logging and changeing as FF extension. I've managed to produce some working code, but it works wrong and looks like triggering on any request method, not only post as needed. Seems like all steps are done accordingly to mozilla tutorials but for some reason it does not work as expected. Here's the snippet.

```
observe: function(subject, topic, data) 
      {
        if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
          var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
          //httpChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Hello", "World", false);
          //console.log("http-on");
          if(httpChannel.requestMethod == "POST")
            {
                console.log("in");
                var uploadChannel = httpChannel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIUploadChannel);
                var uploadStream = uploadChannel.uploadStream;
                uploadStream.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream).
                             seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);
                var binStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"].
                                createInstance(Ci.nsIBinaryInputStream);
                binStream.setInputStream(uploadStream);
                var postBytes = binStream.readByteArray(binStream.available());
                var postString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);
                console.log("read");
                console.log(postString);
            }

        }
      },
```

Thank you for your time!

UPD:

There was an idea todo something like this to filter POST requests

```
var postBytes = binStream.readByteArray(binStream.available());
uploadStream.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream).
             seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);

var postString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);
var tmp = postString.split("\r\n\r\n");

if(tmp[1] && tmp[1].length <= 1024 )
{               
    //log & process
}
```

It works, but I don't know how it will handle different situations.

Comment: So that `httpChannel.requestMethod == 'POST'` is not enough to filer it out? By the way is how I saw someone read the post data as string - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/28624e20bfee2dc128c4

Comment: @Noitidart, hey, thanks for the link, I'll make a not for myself. And yes, looks like this condition is not enough. I visited a site, just before doing form submit, and console was full of  "in" messages and page sources.